# Where can I find a specific dataset?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, dataset, artificial-intelligence, tensorflow-datasets

I am looking for a dataset that would allow me to train my model to output a question generated from the input sentence.

For example,

"Python is a programming language" to "Is Python a programming language?"

To type the questions and the sentences myself would be impossible.
Where can I find a dataset that would help me do this?

Answer (score 0):

You could Try https://datasetsearch.research.google.com/, https://www.kaggle.com/datasets or https://www.tensorflow.org/datasets. You could also try this Dataset from Kaggle https://www.kaggle.com/stackoverflow/pythonquestions

Comment: I already tried these datasets and none of them would have what I'm looking for. Is there a way to generate datasets on my own?

Comment: I did not get that

Comment: you could web scrap data https://towardsdatascience.com/byod-build-your-own-dataset-for-free-67133840dc85